# Как передать модель из контекста в представление

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Хочу отправить список всех ролей из контроллера в представление

```
 public ActionResult RoleAddToUser()
        {
            var roles = this.context.Roles.ToList();

            return this.View(this.context.Roles.ToList());
        }
```

Но не совсем понятно как получить доступ к этому списку из представления.

```
@model ...
```

Answer (score 1):

предположим класс `Role` выглядит следующим образом:

```
class Role
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

тогда что бы вывести список ролей представление может быть таким:

```
@model IEnumerable<Role>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</td>
            <td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Comment: Role это стандатный класс из Identity

Comment: @Radzhab все будет работать, разница только в том что в стандартной реализации `Id` является строкой